# Is there any method to get mutual exclusion in a chef node?

Tags: rest, chef-infra, mutex

For example, If a process updates a node when a chef-client is running the chef-client will overwrite the node data:

1. chef-client gets node data (state 1)
2. The process A gets node data (state 1)
3. The process A updates locally the node data (state 2)
4. This process saves node data (state 2)
5. chef-client updates locally the node data (state 2*)
6. chef-client saves node data, and this node data does not contains the changes from the process A (state 2). The chef-client overwrite the node data. (state 2*)

The same problem occurs, if we have two processes saving node data in the same moment

**EDIT**

We need to external modification because we have a nice UI of Chef server to manage remotely a lot of computers, showing like a tree (similar to LDAP). An administrator can update the value of the recipes from here. This project is OpenSource: https://github.com/gecos-team/

Although we had a semaphore system, we have detected that if we have two or more simultaneous requests, we can have a concurrence problem:

1. The regular case is that the system [works](https://docs.google.com/a/emergya.com/drawings/d/1XnKC0jtzkHEc3KedCGiQsLR42URbKWGCv4Y6NqRRREY/edit?usp=sharing)
2. But sometimes the system [does not work](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1IXQmQ75Qssxz8mXDOxNj4gToFd5bhRtBs-KWo__zgOk/edit?usp=sharing)

**EDIT 2**

[I have added a document with a lot of information about our problem.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CtNeKLeLlyE_fk1e3bDktJ63oIQ5MDANLdriXfrFCvU/edit#)

Comment: No, you have to use something outside of chef to make a lock, or just avoid this kind of process by reviewing your workflow (editing node is usually the mark of snowflakes server which should be avoided)

Comment: Do you know a solution outside of chef? I suppose, it is a common problem.

Comment: No it is not a common problem, use a recipe to let the node update it's data itself and avoid external manipulation of the node object. Other workarounds involve some kind of out of band lock-out mechanism, a REST endpoint somewhere, something like consul, zookeeper or whatever else could do, but you'll have to include the guard in your process anyway.

Comment: The problem is that we don't want to avoid the external manipulation. Of course if we avoid the external manipulation there is not a problem... but it is not a solution :-P another solution?

Comment: None out of those I speak about above. On chef 12 there's an api for the node to report resources state during the run, maybe it could be used, but I Know 0 implementation around this. Maybe chef is not the right tool for your workfow too...

Comment: The main question under this is 'why do you need to modify the node object externally ?' maybe there's other approach to achieve the same thing avoiding this step.

Comment: I have edited the question to give you more information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93717/discussion-between-goin-and-tensibai).

Comment: I'm off work right now, I'll try to have a look at it tomorow ;) (but modifying the run list could be done with a chef-client run instead of modifying the object)

Comment: Is "Process A" another chef-related process? Or is it completely separate from Chef?

Comment: Process A is completely separate from Chef. Process A is a celery task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chef doesn't implement a transaction feature and also it does not re-converge nodes on updates automatically by default. It's open for race conditions which you can try to reduce by updated node attributes from within a chef-client run (right before you do something critical) but you will never end up in a reliable, working setup.

The longer the converge runs, the higher the gap and risk of corruption.

Chef's node attributes are only useful for debugging or modification by the chef-client running on the node itself and pretty much useless in highly concurrent/dynamic environments.

I would use [Consul.io](https://consul.io/) to coordinate semaphores and key/value configuration data in realtime. Access it using chef recipes or LWRPs using one of the various interfaces consul provides (http, DNS, …).

You can implement a very easy push-job task to run chef-client (IMHO easier and more powerful than the chef "push jobs" feature, however not integrated in Chefs' ACL/user management) which also is guarded [by a distributed semaphore](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/semaphore.html) or using the ["Leader Election"](https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/leader-election.html) feature. Of course you'll have to add this logic to your node update script, too.

Chef-client will then retrieve a lock on start and block you from manipulating data while it converges and vice versa.

Comment: Side note: if you wish to control the runlist within consul, a cookbook somewhere wich takes this entry in consul and update the runlist will be needed.

Comment: If you really cant avoid modifying the node object (e.g. for run_list changes) then use consul as a Semphore-service and just wrap chef-client + api modification clients with it. In this case the chef converge doesn't need to  know about the consul-semaphore-wrapping: If chef-client runs, it owns the semaphore.

Comment: I think it is the best answer, it is very near to "Add API wrapped" described in the "Concurrency problem" document linked in the question

Comment: @Goin Can you explain me on what is different between our two answers ?(I don't care for the rep points, just trying to understand how this one answers your problem and mine does not)

Comment: Because I feel it is more generic than your answer, and this answer has more details. But you are right, both are similar. I voted every answer because I think that I must thank your assistance

Answer (score 4):

Throwing what I would do for this case as an answer:

1. Have a distributed lock mechanism like
   [This](https://github.com/thefab/restful-distributed-lock-manager)
   I'm not using it myself, it is just for the idea
2. Build a start/report/error handler which will

   - at start acquire a lock on the node name in the DLM in 1.

     - if it can't abort the run or wait untill the lock is free
   - at end (report or error) release the lock.
3. Modify the External system to do the same as the handler above, aquire a lock before modifying and release when done.
4. Pay attention to the lock lifetime !!! It should be longer than your Chef Run plus a margin, and the UI should ensure its lock is still there before writing and abort if not.

---

A way to get rid of the handler (but you still need a lock for the UI) is to take advantage of the [reporting api](https://docs.chef.io/api_reporting.html) (premium feature of chef 12, free under 25 nodes, license needed upward)

This turn a bit convoluted and need the node to do reporting (so the chef-server url should end with organizations/ and the client version should be above 11.16 or [use the backport](https://github.com/chef/chef-reporting))

Then your can ask about the [runs for a node](https://docs.chef.io/api_reporting.html#reports-nodes-node-runs) and check if there's one at started status for this node, and wait until it is ended.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this answer does not fix my problem :-(

Comment: @Goin according to your comment under Roland's answer, I still don't get why it does not fix your problem. Not the answer your prefer, I've no problem with it but the comment sounds unrelated to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Discovered this one in production and came to the conclusion that there is no safe way to edit the node attributes directly. Leave it to the chef-client :-)

Good news is that there are other more reliable ways to set node attributes. Chef roles and environments can both be edited safely while a client is running and only take effect during the next chef run. Additionally [node attribute precedence rules](https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence) ensure that any settings you make override those that might be made by a recipe.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this answer does not fix my problem :-(

Comment: Did you try role or environment attribute overrides? Of course the change will only take effect on the node object after the next chef run. This was how we worked around this race condition, I see you accepted Roland's answer to use an alternative solution like consul (or etcd or zookeeper). These are obviously better ways to keep this kind of centralized configuration data more real-time.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think that this does not fix my problem, think in 4 concurrent process updating a node.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to avoid Chef node data updates from your external app, and move that desired node configuration to a Chef databag.

So nodes will read Chef node data and configuration databag and write only in node data. And you external app read both but only writes in the databag.

Comment: Thank you very much, but this answer does not fix my problem :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoind a dependency on another external service, perhaps you could use some kind of time slicing.

Roughly: nodes only start a chef-client on odd minutes. Api only update chef data on even minutes (distribute these even minutes if you have more than a queue).